# DocuSign: Multiple base URI for one account?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I have a question regarding base URI with user and account objects in REST API.

To summarize:

- one user can have multiple account attached,
- one account is attached to one company,
- without OAuth, we can get base URI by calling API /login_information,
- with OAuth, we can get base URL by calling API /oauth/userinfo

Is it right ?

If yes, can we say that one base URI is attached to one account and will be the same for every user attached to this account ?

In addition, is it possible to get base URI by calling an endpoint dedicated to the account, and not the user ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you write is correct, you understand this pretty well.
The reason you cannot use an account API endpoint to find the **baseUrl** is the architecture of how this works. The DocuSign code is deployed to many data-centers, but it's the same code. The same APIs run on na2, eu1, au etc. etc. So they are not aware directly that they have a different **baseUri** than other data centers.
The OAuth endpoints are different/separate and can get information from all data centers.
OAuth is always about a specific user, because you cannot login directly to an account, but you have your own user that you use. An account is shared, but each user has their own password.

The only way to do something remotely similar to what you're asking is if you use the [DocuSign organization feature](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide-create-org).

You can then use the [DocuSign Admin API to obtain information about the organization](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/reference/accounts/accounts/getorganizations/) and the accounts in it. That information includes a **siteId** that tells you if it's on na1, na2, eu1 etc. Using that you can construct the **baseURI**.
Lots of limitations to this, so not sure that would help you.